# Can you reuse the 'clear' button graphic (circle with an 'x' in it) from a UITextField in your own custom control?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, ios12

We have a custom date picker control that we want the user to be able to clear, the same way they clear a `UITextField`.  However, we can't find the graphic representing the clear button. Is that available to be used elsewhere?

***Update: We are using iOS 12 so we can't use `xmark.circle.fill` as suggested below as it appears that's only for iOS 13 and later.***

We were originally thinking to just use a `UITextField` but we don't want the user to be able to interact with it at all except for clearing the value. (When you tap on it, we display a date picker UI.)

So is this graphic available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the system image "xmark.circle" or "xmark.circle.fill"? This might be what you are looking for. Just change the tint to what works for you.

[xmark.circle.fill](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frgvp.png)

Comment: Would've been perfect... BUT... apparently that's only available in iOS 13 or later.  We need iOS 12.  Adding that tag now.  Still, voted you up bc this is awesome!

Comment: Oops! I’m away from my laptop but maybe try searching Apple’s iOS Sketch resource https://developer.apple.com/design/resources/. I can check when I get back.

Comment: I was able to get from iOS 13 Sketch -> UI Elements + Design Templates + Guides -> UIElements+DesignTemplates+Guides. Then in Sketch from UIElements - Controls -> Textfields and I detached the clear button and I cut it out and pasted in a new canvas.

Comment: Actually, marking this as the answer because you can use that app to export the SVG, then use that.  Sure it doesn't have all the cool SF Symbol stuff, but it doesn't have to for our needs. :)